# SaltStack - Unable to update mine_function

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

I'm unable to change the `mine_function` on the minion hosts. How can I make changes to the function and push them to all minions?

`cat /etc/salt/cloud:`

```
minion:
  mine_functions:
    internal_ip:
      - mine_function: grains.get
      - ip_interfaces:eth0:0
    external_ip:
      - mine_function: grains.get
      - ip_interfaces:eth1:0
```

I want to change the `external_ip` function as below. But I'm not sure how to push these changes to all minions. `mine_interval` is set to 1 minute but the changes aren't picked up by minions.

```
external_ip:
  - mine_function: network.ip_addrs
  - cidr: 172.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: You need to restart the services after changing their config.

Comment: I've already restarted both minion and master. it seems like `/etc/salt/cloud` is used only for provisioning. I'm not sure how to make changes to minions mine_functions after provisioning.

Comment: The config will be installed on the actual minions. Change it there.